# Can't set PictureBox location in panel

Tags: c#, panel, location

I have a created a panel. 
This has autoscroll = true

At the start i added 6 pictureboxes that are 256x256 with images.
I store the last picturebox location, so that i know where to put a new picturebox.

I also add a picturebox to the upper right of the panel(location(8744,8744)), so that the panel will stretch to 9000px.

Later on when i scroll around in the panel, i can push a button and add a picturebox to the panel. The problem is that when i set the location of the picturebox and add it to the panel, it comes out totally wrong, visually.

Code for adding more images.

```
private void addPictureBox(Point pixelCoordinates, Bitmap image)
{
        PictureBox pNewImage = new PictureBox();
        imagePanel.Controls.Add(pNewImage);

        pNewImage.Image      = image;
        pNewImage.Name       = "image_:" + pixelCoordinates.X + "_" + pixelCoordinates.Y;
        pNewImage.Location   = pixelCoordinates;
        pNewImage.Size       = new System.Drawing.Size(256, 256);
        pNewImage.Visible    = true;
        pNewImage.BackColor  = Color.White;

        imagePanel.Update();

}
```

If i debug and watches the panel, it says that the new picturebox has the location i set, but visually, it's not.

I have noticed that this is what really happens:
The location of the picturebox is from where i have scrolled + location.X.

Anyone got an idea how i can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pictureboxes are being added after you have scrolled away from the coordinates 0,0 you may need to account for this by adding the scroll amount to pixelCoordinates. Try using `imagePanel.VerticalScroll.Value` and `imagePanel.HorizontalScroll.Value` in your calculations.

Comment: i'll try that later again. I tried it yesterday, but i think i used the scrollbar values a bit after i had created the images. And that is obviously wrong. i'll save the scrollbar position in a hashtable with the downloaded image's pixelcoordinate, so that i can subtract the scrollbarposition from the pixelcoordinates of the image.